# Theorem 3.27 of Rudin's Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, topological-vector-spaces

I have a small question about the proof of Theorem 3.27 of Rudin's Functional Analysis. I understood everything else in the proof, but there's one small piece I'm not able to figure out.

So what we are trying to prove is that there exist $y \in H$, where $H = co(f(Q))$ such that $\Lambda y = \int_{Q}(\Lambda f)d\mu \; \forall \Lambda \in X^*$. Rudin then defined $E_L$ to be the set of $y \in \bar H$ that satisfies the previous integral $\forall \Lambda \in L$ where $L$ is finite and $L = \{\Lambda_1, ... \Lambda_n\}$.

He then claims that each $E_L$ is closed by continuity of $\Lambda$. This is the part I don't understand - why is $E_L$ closed? Does $\cup\Lambda {y}$ for all y satisfying the integral need to be a closed set?

Thanks in advance to everyone for helping out!

Here is the whole theorem and proof by Rudin:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you have
$$
E_L=\bigcap_{j=1}^nE_{\Lambda_j}. 
$$
So it is enough to show that a single $E_{\Lambda}$ is closed.

A set is closed if and only if it contains all its limit points. Suppose that $\{y_j\}\subset E_L$ is a net that converges to $y\in\bar H$. Then, because $\Lambda$ is continuous,
$$
\Lambda y=\lim_j\Lambda y_j=\int_Q(\Lambda f)\,d\mu. 
$$